# How i can install BusyBox on Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization, busybox

How i can  install BusyBox on Virtual Machine? For instance, VMVare or VirtualBox? Where I can see some manuals about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Busybox alone in a virtual machine.

From the [Busybox FAQ](http://busybox.net/FAQ.html#build_system):

> Busybox is a package that replaces a dozen standard packages, but it is not by itself a complete bootable system.

Comment: ... but, may be there is a iso file of linux distribute, based on busybox, which i can use on Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 0):

Although **busybox being a package and therefoe unable to boot by itself**, there's a linux distribution called 4MLinux, its ["Core" edition](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux4m/files/9.0/livecd/) is a bare, minimal distro, under 5 MB in size, that relies on busybox.

From the official [help file](http://4mlinux.com/help.txt):

```
The minimal (core) 4MLinux system includes:
   /bin/busybox (BusyBox),
   /bin/sh (symlink to BusyBox),
   /dev/null (device node),
   /etc/init.d/rcS (sysinit script),
   /lib/ld-2.18.so (glibc library required by Busybox),
   /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (symlink to ld-2.18.so),
   /lib/libc-2.18.so (glibc library required by Busybox),
   /lib/libc.so.6 (symlink to libc-2.18.so),
   /lib/libm-2.18.so (glibc library required by Busybox),
   /lib/libm.so.6 (symlink to libm-2.18.so),
   /sbin/init (symlink to Busybox).
   The above set of files is enough  to boot 4MLinux using
   some kind of  boot disk. All the  other essential files
   and directories are created/installed by rcS during the
   first startup.
```